# Uploading an executable Html File To QR Code

Tags: php, html, qr-code

Is there a way to make a QR code that contains an html file? (no URL)
Like a QR that, scanned, makes your smartphone read the html code and run it in your browser without using a public server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

QR codes contain text.

While it would be possible to write a reader that could detect HTML and parse it automatically, that isn't normal behaviour.

The closest you could get would be a `data:` scheme URL.

Comment: Could you explain me better or tell me where I can learn how to do it? Also is it so difficult to write a reader for html?

Comment: The problem is that a data: URL is a text not a link so scanning the QR results only in a text string

Comment: As I said, a `data:` scheme URL is *the closest you can get*. If the particular QR code reading software being used doesn't recognise it as a link and make it easy to open it in a browser, then that's just a shame.